# No cqlsh on Cassandra install on CentOS 7.2

Tags: installation, cassandra-2.0, centos7, cqlsh

I installed `cassandra` but I do not see `cqlsh`. I have anaconda so I installed `cqlsh` from that

```
pip install cqlsh 
Successfully installed cqlsh-5.0.3
```

When I try to connect to cassandra I get this error

```
[idf@node1 sbin]$ cqlsh 10.0.0.60
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.0.0.60': ProtocolError("cql_version '3.3.1' is not supported by remote (w/ native protocol). Supported versions: [u'3.1.7']",)})

[idf@node1 sbin]$ cqlsh 10.0.0.60 9160
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.0.0.60': ConnectionShutdown('Connection <AsyncoreConnection(140356880106448) 10.0.0.60:9160 (closed)> is already closed',)})
[idf@node1 sbin]$
```

Where do I find the cqlsh that comes with cassandra from datastax? Or if the above is supposed to work, what do I need to do?

Comment: That error is because the cqlsh you installed does not match the server. How did you install Cassandra? I don't know of any ways that do not include cqlsh. Maybe it's just not in your path.

Comment: No, the problem is that I have anaconda installed and the CentOS python comes later in the path. So it is picking up Anaconda python. Since the site-package is with the system python, it won't work. If I try to install the anaconda version of cqlsh, there is a version incompatibility. Frustrating.

Comment: I solved it by copying the cqlsh directory to the anaconda site-packages directory

Answer (score 2):

Try connecting like this:

> $ cqlsh 10.0.0.60 9042 -u -p --cqlversion="3.1.7"

Answer (score 0):

If anaconda2 is pre-installed in the system, `cqlsh` doesn't work since it cannot import `cqlshlib`. Firstly, you have to install `cqlsh` inside anaconda and then overwrite `cqlshlib` with the one installed at system level:

```
pip install cqlsh
find /usr/lib/ -name cqlshlib | xargs cp -R -t ~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cqlshlib/
```